# Flash projector displays black screen when video played

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a desktop executable projector file for use in a presentation.

I have set the fscommand to display the projector in fullscreen on launch.

Everything works fine until we get to the video slide at which point whilst in full screen the video slide is totally blacked out, you can't view anything.

If full screen is exited the slide is view able again but the video does not show unless I go forward a slide and then back.

Does anyone know why this would be?

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");

import flash.media.SoundMixer;  
import gs.TweenMax;
import gs.easing.*;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

this.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration from settings. Seems to be something VGA-related...

Comment: Also, do you confirm that you can see the video in a browser or in non-fullscreen mode?

Comment: Had exactly the same issue. Tried with hardware acceleration disabled, but still no luck. @Brob, Have you resolved this issue by any chance ?